# Почему не выводит в консоль числа в классическом, вещественном представлении при значении E <= -4 или E >= 7?

Tags: java, вывод, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста, почему при выводе в консоль чисел, со степенью экспоненты меньшей или равной -4, вывод происходит в экспоненциальной форме? 
Т. е. если написать:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1E-3;
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

То вывод: 0.001 
Тогда как для:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 1E-4;
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

Вывод: 1E-4. Ну и так далее для любой степени, меньшей чем -4.
А для положительных степеней диапазон до 6 включительно, а потом опять начинается вывод через E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что именно так предусмотрено [в официальной документации Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)):

> If m is greater than or equal to 10^-3 but less than 10^7, then it is
> represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no leading
> zeroes, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by one or more decimal
> digits representing the fractional part of m.

> If m is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is
> represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation.

В переводе получается именно то, что вы написали в вопросе:
от 10^-3(включительно) до 10^7(исключительно) используется простой и всем понятный формат десятичной дроби.
Вне этих диапазонов - формат числа с плавающей точкой.

Указанное поведение является "поведением по умолчанию", которое можно менять, как, например, указано в ответе @Qwertiy♦

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("a = %f%n", a);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1263455/edit)